# Using Microsoft bot framework with dynamic dialog

Tags: botframework

Dears ,
         I would like to know how can i make the dialog dynamic in microsoft bot framework? Now from the code samples it's all using enums to represent values , but how if the values shall be returned from a service?

I also have another question , where can I find the luis intents that are being used in the samples? and from where the word " Please select " comes from the github bot builder sample , especially the pizzabot .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I blogged about [Dynamic FormFlow Forms in Bot Builder](http://mayoster.blogspot.com/2016/05/dynamic-formflow-forms-in-bot-builder.html). This was written for FormFlow. I haven't figured out how to get string arrays to work with dialogs or if there might be a bug there.

The Prompts are using the defaults for properties in the [PizzaOrder](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/PizzaBot/Pizza.cs) class. and you can change them with Prompt and Template attributes. The [SandwichBot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/PizzaBot/Pizza.cs) explanation in the docs covers these attributes.

I don't know if Microsoft opened the LUIS intents for PizzaBot (or if it's practical to let the general public view your original model). Maybe you can visit their [Feedback](https://feedback.botframework.com/) site and ask them to share the JSON for the LUIS PizzaBot model. The [LUIS video tutorial and docs](https://www.luis.ai/Help) might help if you want to create your own model and replace the LUIS model tokens with your own.

Comment: Here you will find the LUIS Model for the PizzaBot: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/commit/a7a61acbd24eb50122cbafad0fbc10f717263c66 (it's still on the develop branch). Also, the Annotated Sandwich Bot sample is using dynamic fields https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/AnnotatedSandwichBot/AnnotatedSandwich.cs#L112

Comment: Joe, you seem to understand this Bot Builder malarky a great deal more than most I've seen around on here. I'm struggling to figure out a way to get the bot to ask different questions based on the previous answer.

So, for example:
Bot1: Do you have siblings?
User: Yes

(User answers yes and is taken to a further question about their siblings. User answers no, they are taken to a different question). I have been using FormFlow and the SandwichBot as an example for testing.